# Background with a percentage in Android Layout

Tags: android

What I want to achieve is, I want to draw a box which wraps a text. The background color will fill percentage of the wrapper and that percentage will be a variable.

How can I achieve this in Android layout?

(If this was an HTML project, I would set two divs (parent/child): Parent would be relative and child would be absolute. So that I would have positioned child div at the bottom and set height as percentage.)

[image]
https://www.autodraw.com/share/5MLGMPAVWLNH

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ConstraintLayout and set `app:layout_constraintHeight_percent` of `textView` to any value between 0 and 1.

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:textSize="64sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:background="#f9d048"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".5"
            />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```